# Struts2 Ajax CORS

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

I'm trying to call my struts2 action call from another domain. Struts2 is on **localhost:8080** while the one who will make the ajax call is on another one, **localhost:3000**. I've tried to put a `sample.json` file on my struts2 project folder under web folder, I can do an ajax call on the `sample.json` file. But the problem is, when i'm trying to request to my action class, I get an error which says:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/workforce/loginAction. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My problem is, I can do an ajax call on the sample json file under the same project `http://localhost:8080/sample.json`but not with my struts2 action class?

Struts2 action:

```
package com.workforce.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.workforce.models.UserModel;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<UserModel>{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private UserModel user = new UserModel();

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    user.setEmail("sampleemail");
    user.setPassword("12345");

    System.out.println(user.getEmail());
    System.out.println(user.getPassword());

    return SUCCESS;
}

@Override
public UserModel getModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return user;
}
}
```

struts2 xml

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<package name="default" extends="struts-default, json-default">

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="json" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <action name="loginAction" class="com.workforce.actions.LoginAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="myStack" />
        <result name="success" type="json"/>

        <result name="input" type="json">
            <param name="statusCode">500</param>
            <param name="errorCode">500</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Ajax call

```
var request = {
            url: "http://localhost:8080/workforce/loginAction",
            method: "POST",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },  
            data: {
                user: self.user
            }
        };

        $http(request).then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
```

**UPDATED**

I've tried to comment out my struts2 config in web.xml and create a sample servlet.. And it works! I just want to know how can I configure `CorsFilter` with `Struts2 Filter`

Comment: http://localhost:8080/workforce/sample.json this url works and I can retrieve the data inside it.

Comment: Actually, I have already added it in my web.xml i just didn't put it up there but I already updated my answer to show my S2 config. Do I need to implement on my action class the CorsFilter? I just put it in my web.xml and nothing follows.

Comment: You need to debug to see -> Is your `CorsFilter` getting called for action url? What about json file url?

Comment: It is part of the tomcat application server right? Is there a difference between action url and the json file url?

Comment: Are you sure that you have exact same web.xml as you've shown?

Answer (score 2):

After a while, I've solved it by putting first the `CorsFilter` rather than `Struts2 Filter`. It now works. Thanks.

Comment: And that is why there was a comment: *Are you sure that you have exact same web.xml as you've shown?*

Comment: My bad, I just added the struts2 config when you have requested it. But, initially it was on top of CorsFilter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

U can check the solution of CORS in struts. It's a simple demo application which resolves the problem of CORS in struts2.

https://github.com/rohitmehlawat/struts-cors